# How to deal with Skewness on distribution in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, load-balancing, distributed-computing

I'm having a problem with the distribution of data in spark cluster because many objects that I need to be processed together have the same key. Consequently, many tasks quickly end but one of the tasks continues runing until the executor's memory boundaries and the cluster application get error and stop. the image shows what happens inside the history server.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one of the biggest challenges in distributed computing: Distribute the payload of every task, so that you get maximum performance.

In other words, you need every task's workload to be equibalanced w.r.t. to the other tasks.

You need to re-apporach your problem and solve it in another way (find a "secondary" key as suggested), or try executing a job that will work only on the big task (i.e. distribute the task itself).

Comment: I concur, I'd definitely work on the origin of the skew in a different task trying to find a "secondary" key to partition on and work.